# Update wordpress post to draft if condition is true

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the below code to delete the rows from an ACF repeater field with expired date and when the number of rows reaches zero then update the post to draft mode or private mode. 
But somethings are not woring (The draft thing is not working.)

```
$ap = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_0_start_date',true);
$startdate = date("Ymd", strtotime($ap));
$todaydate = date("Ymd");
if(strtotime($todaydate) > strtotime($startdate) && !empty($ap)){
    $del_data = array(
                    'Ref' => 'sub_seminars_0_ref',
                    'Start date' => 'sub_seminars_0_start_date',
                    'End Date' => 'sub_seminars_0_end_date',
                    'Venue' => 'sub_seminars_0_venue',
                    'Fees' => 'sub_seminars_0_fees',
                    'CPE Credits' => 'sub_seminars_0_cpe_credits'
        );
    delete_row('sub_seminars', 1);
    $row = count( get_field('sub_seminars') );
    if ($row == 0) {
        $postid = $post->ID; //Supply post-Id here $post->ID.
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'    =>  $postid,
            'post_status'   =>  'draft'
        ));

    }
}
```

Please can anybody tell me what is wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: check your code log. `$row == 0` is true or false? do if block run at all?

Comment: The condition $row == 0 is true still no luck !!

Comment: Check `$post->ID` is set or not. your code is correct!!

Comment: Turns out something is wrong with my condition and I don't know what !!

Comment: Test this code http://pastebin.com/Fa6Fp9be! See database  [phpmyadmin] changes after run code

Comment: @MahdiY, thanks for the help but the code doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $rows = get_field('sub_seminars');
         $row_count = count($rows);
       // $row_count = count($rows);
        if ($rows == 0) {
           $my_post = array(
               'ID'     => $post->ID,
               'post_status'   =>  'draft'
                );
                wp_update_post($my_post);
            }
```

use the above code it fixed the problem for me.